# Favicon Appears at App start in IE but then, "Dissapears" when a part of URL is updated

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, internet-explorer, href

I am working on a huge Java Web App (Having JSP , Java script and Servlets etc).
It grabs the Favicon which is working fine and appears on the Tab in IE at http://localhost:8080/Release/main

However there is java script functionality which updates the link and modifies the URL a bit at the end so http://localhost:8080/Release/main is changed to http://localhost:8080/Release/list/Somenting.

As soon as that happens the Favicon dissapears. If I refresh the page where favicon has dissapeared, then it brings the favicon back, but I cannot do this as there are many sublinks generated by the app.

The code to originally bring the favicon (WHICH IS WORKING PROPERLY) is :

```
     <link rel="icon" href="images/fav.ico" type="image/x-icon">
     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/fav.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

There are various articles on internet which discuss that the favicon is NOT appearing. Here I do not have that issue. It appears fine but then Dissapears when a part of URL is changed.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: If you expect us to be able to visit those URLs, please be aware that localhost is only accessible on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use relative path then start it from root directory (/images/fav.ico) or use absolute paht (https://domain.ltd/path/images/fav.ico) instead.

Comment: I told that the icon is already showing up. However it dissapears when the URL is changed. Please read the question first.

Comment: as long as URL still in the same level of directory then it should work (trailing slash can break this too). So I guess you may just confuse - but if you don't, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks !! the url changes from http://localhost:8080/Release/main to http://localhost:8080/Release/list 

is this considered that Directory level is changed ? I dont understand what is exactly meant by this here

Comment: LOL I don't understand too, glade you fixed this. BTW, check network tab it can tell where it attempt to fetch favicon.

Comment: Okay I will. Actually the issue is not fixed yet

Answer (score 0):

When you are at http://localhost:8080/Release/main the favicon is located at http://localhost:8080/Release/main/images/fav.ico according to your link tags.

Since you didn't change those tags, as soon as you go to http://localhost:8080/Release/list/Somenting the browser expects to find the favicon at http://localhost:8080/Release/list/Somenting/images/fav.ico because you are using a path relative to your current location in your link tags.

A possible solution would be to use an absolute URL.

```
 <link rel="icon" href="/Release/main/images/fav.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Release/main/images/fav.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Inserting the slash at the beginning of the URL changes the behaviour such that the URL is relative to localhost, rather than your current location.